# Confused on a for loop for a hangman game?

Tags: python

The hangman code that I am referencing comes from the [*Invent Your Own Games with Python*](https://inventwithpython.com/invent4thed/chapter8.html) book:

In the function that displays the game board, there is a for loop that replaces a string composed of underscores with the correct, guessed letters corresponding to whatever the secretWord is:

```
    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1]
```

I have trouble trying to understand and visualize the line `blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1]`
Let's say `secretWord = "otter"` and `blanks = "_____"` (five underscores). How exactly would the for loop work?

Comment: You'd figure people writing Python books would know how to write readable loops, I don't blame you for not understanding what's going on. First of all, where is the `enumerate`?!

Comment: There's a typo which no one seems to have spotted: it should be `blanks[i+1:]`, not `blanks[i+1]`. You can find out what each part is by printing them.

Comment: btw, isn't `''.join(c if c in correctletters else '_' for c in secretWord)` equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(len(secretWord)):
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        # blanks = the underscores from 0 to i found in blanks
        # + the secret letter at index i in secretWord
        # + the underscores from i+1 to the end found in blanks
        blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]
```

Example:

```
blanks = _____ (5 underscores)
secretWord = Hi

lets assume that 'i' is in correct letters and 'h' is not
(loop 2 times since len('hi') == 2)
------------------------------------------------------
First iteration:

if 'h' in correctLetters (its not so skip):
------------------------------------------------------
Second iteration:

'i' is in correctLetters

blanks = __ (underscores from 0 to 1 in blanks) 
   + 'i' (the letter at secretWord[1]) 
   + __ (blanks[2:onward] - the rest of the underscores ignoring the one where the letter goes)
```

Apply the same logic to a longer word like Otter and what happens is that it will continue to replace the underscores in blanks with the letters from secretWord that are found in correctLetters. The result of secretWord otter and blanks = _____ would mean that blanks = otter

Answer (score 2):

Let's imagine you got the letter 't' correct.
So correctLetters=['t'] and we go through our secret word, to see where the t appears.

For i = 0 nothing happens, 'o' is not in our correctLetters.
For i = 1 we got the 't', it's part of correctLetters, so we are able to do the magic with the blanks:

| blanks[:i] gets the String until position i=1, so here: '_'
secretWord[i] gives you the 't', as i=1
blanks[i+1] gives you all the rest of the string, starting from position i+1=2 -> ___

Overall you have _t___ after this iteration.

You'll we do the same again with another t (i=2 now) and you'll have:
blanks = _tt__

And then it's super easy to guess Otter, right ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(secretWord)):
# i is index of secretword
  if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
  # checking if letter secretWord[i] is in correctletters
  # if it is in, replace _ in blacks  to secretWord[i]
  # recreate blank list by using everything before index i, secretWord[i], and everything after index i
    blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1]
```